# Select tabBarController index programatically from other tabBar index

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have HomeViewController thats is located as UINavigation root view controller of main tabBarController at index 0. Also I have SecondViewController as UINavigation root view controller on tab index 1 and I need to switch tab programatically . So when I finish edit action in SecondViewController I need to show tab index 0 and his nested UINavigation root view controller.

I tried to use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

this change index but view controller is not changed. It stays on same view.

Also tried

```
self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

same result as above :(

this is all for iOS 8.0+

Comment: That is the correct way to switch indexes, you may have a bug in your code  elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your `tabBarController` to control the selection. Call this function from your viewControllers. In the function just call [self setSelectedIndex:xxx] to change the tab.

Comment: Nop Not working :(  same as above .. index is changed but view controller visible is still old one.